# TickCount() deprecated in Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, deprecated

I am using `TickCount()` to determine the time difference between events or time required to run a certain piece of code. But it is [deprecated](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Memory_Manag_nt_Utilities/Memory_Manag_nt_Utilities.pdf) in OS X 10.8.
Therefore, I needed an alternative for the same.

Comment: `$ man TickCount: No manual entry for TickCount`

Comment: Please click on deprecated link in the original post and search for TickCount for documentation.

Comment: OK, got it.  I'd never even heard of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you want to measure absolute time, use `gettimeofday()`.  This gives you the date, e.g., "Thu Nov 22 07:48:52 UTC 2012".  This is not always suitable for measuring differences between events because the time reported by `gettimeofday()` can jump forwards or backwards if the user changes the clock.
2. If you want to measure relative time, `mach_absolute_time()`.  This lets you measure the difference between two events, e.g., "15.410 s".  This does not give absolute times, but is always monotonic.
3. If you want to measure CPU time, use `clock()`.  This is *often* but not always the way you measure the performance of a piece of code.  It doesn't count time spent on IO, or impact on system speed, so it should only be used when you know you are measuring something CPU bound.

I'm surprised that `TickCount()` wasn't deprecated earlier.  It's really an OS 9 and earlier thing.

Comment: I believe `mach_absolute_time()` will serve my purpose. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @dDarkLORD `gettimeofday()` is more portable though.

Comment: @trojanfoe: No sense in using the portable function if it doesn't do what you want.  On Linux you'd use `clock_gettime()`, on OS X you'd use `mach_absolute_time()`, neither of which is available on the other operating system.

Answer (score 1):

While this API may not be suitable for new development, if you find yourself in need of an identical API, it can be re-implemented as follows:

```
uint32_t TickCount() {
    uint64_t mat = mach_absolute_time();
    uint32_t mul = 0x80d9594e;
    return ((((0xffffffff & mat) * mul) >> 32) + (mat >> 32) * mul) >> 23;
}
```

The above implementation was created through analysis of `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore`, and was briefly unit-tested against the deprecated `TickCount` with LLDB by altering the registers returned by `mach_absolute_time`.